# python cx_Oracle cursor returns no rows for valid query

Tags: python, sql, cx-oracle, database-cursor, fetchall

Beating my head against my desk on this one.

My cx_Oracle cursor is returning no rows for a valid query and I cannot figure out why.

The same connection returns expected results from other tables in same schema... for example if I simply change the referenced table name in the query from TABLE_A to TABLE_B it works fine.

The query works fine in SQL Developer/SQL Plus using the same user/connection string. I copied/pasted from  cursor.statement during debug to verify exactly same statement, no typos.

I have reduced the queries to the simplest form possible;

```
1. select * from SCHEMA.TABLE_A
```

and

```
2. select * from SCHEMA.TABLE_B
```

Query 1 returns no rows when executed using cx_Oracle, but DOES return expected rows in SQLPlus/SQL Developer, etc.

Query 2 works as expected using cx_Oracle

I have verified privileges - but this is obviously working as I am using (and verified) the user/connection is same in cx_Oracle as in SQL tools.

the code couldn't be reduced/simplified anymore I do not think to isolate the problem - but I am probably being blind to something really obvious:

```
import cx_Oracle

db_conn=cx_Oracle.connect('user/password@localhost:1521/TEST_PDB')
cur = db_conn.cursor()
qry = 'select * from SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_A'
cur.execute(qry)
```

> {cx_Oracle.Cursor on {cx_Oracle.Connection to user@localhost:1521/TEST_PDB}}

```
cur.fetchall()
```

> []

```
cur.rowcount
```

> 0

Yet, the other table/query works:

```
qry = 'select * from SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_B'
cur.execute(qry)
cur.fetchall()
```

> [(12320573611891L, '23.5.2126981', 0, 'NEW', 'UPDATE', datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 24, 9, 0), 48, 0, None, None )]

This is the ONLY table I have encountered this issue with - that I know of so far.

I am using Oracle 12c, python 2.7.11 64bit, and ojdbc6.jar, and 64bit InstantClient

Any ideas ?
Spot anything where my eyes or brain is just not seeing the obvious ?

Comment: What are the actual names of the tables? *Table_A* might be an [Oracle reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out where I was being blind to the issue.

The records were not COMMITED.
I was able to query the records in the session in which I inserted them (SQL Developer), using the same user.

Which led to "what the heck is going on"
I should have known / better.

Comment: You can help reduce the list of questions without accepted Answers, or even any answer, by accepting your own Answer.  Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it for more information on answering your own question.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me some time! I Like you said - I also should have known this was the issue. Changes not commit has caught me out before!

Comment: So, for cx_oracle after `execute` function `connection.commit()` worked for me.